# Location of 'insertion point' after pasting (programmatically)

Tags: python, c++, linux, command-line-interface

I wish to know "how", after pasting, the position of the cursor is determent (like with zen coding) programmatically.

With the 'insertion point' I intend to say: that blinking thing where our text shows up when we type.

So, let's say I paste this: `'<text>%insertion point</text>'`
I want the 'insertion point' to be at a specific location (in this example at %insertion point).

**Some details:**

1. I work with/on Linux (Ubuntu/Fluxbox)
2. Language doesn't really matter (prefer: Python, C, C++ (must be compatible with linux))
3. With pasting I intend: plain pasting in any text area (not in a terminal)

**What I'm 'not' looking for:**

1. a desktop program to do this, unless it's scriptable (such as shell
   tools)
2. a text editor that provide this functionality (such as a vim module)

I'm also curious about tabbing to the next selection so i.e.:

```
<text>%first</text><detail>%second</detail>
```

If there is a better place on the internet for asking my question, please let me know about it.
Any information that would point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for considering my question

EDIT:
**I should mention that it doesn't necessary have to be after pasting, the important thing is to manipulate the location of the 'insertion point'.**

Comment: This depends on what program you're pasting text into, but isn't the cursor generally placed at the end of the pasted text?

Comment: Generally yes, the location is at the end of the pasted text. What I'm looking for is a way to alter this default behavior. Let's say I would write a script/program that has paste functionality that would overwrite this 'default' behavior, what would be a a way to go about it?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? It sounds like there might be another solution you haven't considered.

Comment: All I can say about it is that I need 'something' that would manipulate the current 'insertion point' location. Maybe a shell tool like 'xdotool' or a module for Python that gives me such functionality.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that it doesn't necessary have to be after I paste, the important thing is to manipulate the location of the 'insertion point'.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `xvkbd` to send the paste key combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by a series of <kbd><-</kbd> (left arrow) keys to accomplish the template behaviour and then map a Fluxbox keyboard shortcut to executing this command

The command would be something like

```
xvkbd -text "\Cv\[Left]\[Left]\[Left]\[Left]"
```

Then assign it to a shortcut in your `~/.fluxbox/keys` file (Mod1 is Windows key)

```
Mod1 P :ExecCommand xvkbd -text "\Cv\[Left]\[Left]\[Left]\[Left]"
```

However this would need to be customised somehow for each template, and won't work for applications where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is not "paste" (like xterm). Perhaps for common templates you could just hardcode them to different shortcuts

```
Mod1 T :ExecCommand xvkbd -text "<text></text>\[Left]\[Left]\[Left]\[Left]\[Left]\[Left]\[Left]"
```

I suspect you're going to have a better time if you just customise each editor to offer this functionality separately.

**EDIT**

Here's a Python script that reads from stdin and writes output suitable for `xvkbd`. It uses the percent sign as the insertion point (eg `<text>%</text>`), so you need to escape any real percent signs with a backslash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re

clip = sys.stdin.read()
# split on percent sign not prefixed by backslash
parts = re.split(r'(?<!\\)%', clip, 1)
# un-escape percent sign
parts = [p.replace('\\%', '%') for p in parts]
tail_len = len(parts[-1])

print(''.join(parts) + '\[Left]' * tail_len)
```

You need to pipe the clipboard to it and then pass the result to `xvkbd`. I'm using `xclip` here to output the X clipboard to stdout

```
xclip -out | python pastetemplate.py | xargs -0 -I{} xvkbd -text "{}"
```

It still has the problem of taking a while to move the cursor, however it does automate the prior process.

I really don't think you're going to have any luck moving the cursor programmatically, as I imagine you'd have to use a different automation library depending on the GUI toolkit of the target app (eg GTK, QT, Flash, etc). However if you target a specific app or toolkit, you might be able to work it out.

Comment: This is similar to something I have already tried with 'xdotool' which can also send keystrokes. However, this is not very practical, consider sending 'Left' 50 times or so, that's just to slow, you would actually see the 'insertion thing' move on screen. I'm looking for a solution that would just manipulate the 'insertion position' to x amount offset. So for example 'move left 50' instantly.

Comment: With 'xdotool' you can do something like 'xdotool getwindowfocus key ctrl+v shift+ctrl+v' which would solve the problem for pasting in a terminal. Also, you can test 'if' the current window is a terminal or something else and respond correctly (that is, use ctrl+v or shift+ctrl+v)

Answer (score 0):

Vim stores the position of the previously yanked / pasted / changed text with 2 registers namely `'[` for start line and `']` for the other end. There are character registers as well to know the exact character virtual column of start & end, read `:h '[` for more info.

Comment: I'm not sure if we understand each other, as I have mentioned I'm not looking for functionality inside of a editor like vi[m]. Maybe I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: Your question was tagged with vim so I assumed it was, my bad.

Comment: I removed the 'vim' tag to prevent confusion.